# Instructional example employing \cs_generate_variant:Nn

Tags: expl3

With `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` one can derive new function variants from a base variant by just giving the original, full function name (`N`) and the argument specifiers for the function to derive (`n`).

The description gives an a idea of its use.  But I would like to see a self contained example.

Answers using `\cs_generate_variant` on this site are generally with empty code blocks.  The focus is never practical.  At other times, the question is about a problem, meaning that the code is defective and thus not intended for learning purposes.

Comment: It really doesn't make sense to ask new questions for each section of the expl3 documentation.  a `VV` variant of your command would take the value of two variables as the arguments rather than the `nn` version which takes the literal argument tokens.

Comment: see page 32 and following of interface3.pdf

Comment: If I do everything in one go, I will get indigestion.

Comment: You could try reading the documentation and if you get a tex problem make a real example and ask about that, just asking dozens of vague open ended questions with no actual example apart from fragments of code out of context isn't a useful way to use this site

Comment: I did.  But because one hardly finds any simple examples about what is going on (most things left in abstract description), I simply do not assimilate the implications for practical use.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are asking me for examples when the person needing them is myself.

Comment: there are [1680 postings using this command on this site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Ccs_generate_variant%3ANn)

Comment: The problem with those answers is that the code blocks for each example is always empty. The focus is never practical.  At other times, the question is about a problem, meaning that the code is defective and thus not intended for learning purposes.

Comment: I doubt very much that you reviewed over 1000 answers in an hour and can claim that none of them can help you. Also most answers on the site solve a concrete problem and so  are typically very practical. A person willing to learn can get a lot out of them.

Comment: Have not arrived at that stage yet.

Comment: The solution of these people is to close a question asking for an example.

Comment: Even though this question has been tagged as showing research effor, is useful and clear.